# Does anyone have the lyrics and meaning of Kulusizi by Dixie Kwankwa?

Tags: folk

Dixie Kwankwa was popular in Ghana and Zambia in the 1960s. I've tried to find the lyrics for  [Kulusizi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKaeGZ7tHVA) but nobody seems to have it online as she doesn't have much of a following today.

Extra points if anyone knows the language and translation of the song. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The song seems to be in Zulu. I've tried my best to translate it using a [Zulu-English dictionary](https://isizulu.net/). Here's my best-effort translation which I've turned into a community wiki. Would be very grateful to any Zulu speaker who is able to confirm/edit.

**Zulu Lyrics**

Kulusizi Silambile
Kulusizi kulelizwe
(x2)

Abandanga babantwana
Abasasi balambile
(x2)

Kulusizi kulelizwe
(x2)

**English Translation**

Sadly we are hungry
It is sad in this world
(x2)

The children did not multiply
They are not delighted and were hungry
(x2)

It is sad in this world
(x2)